# Oracle PL/SQL: Conditional Where Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can someone guide me on how to approach the following:

```
x CHAR:= 'Y'; --VARIABLE

SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description
FROM Table1 a
WHERE (IF x = 'Y' THEN 
    a.name = parameter /*FILTER BY NAME*/
    ELSE 
    /*BRING ALL (NO NAME FILTER*/);
```

I'm trying to do a conditional `WHERE` CLAUSE. `IF x = 'Y'` Then filter by name; Else bring all names... what would be the best method for performing the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include both conditions in an `OR` statement to do this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description
FROM   Table1 a
WHERE  (x != 'Y' OR
       (x = 'Y' AND a.name = parameter))
```

If `X` is anything other than `Y`, all records will be pulled, otherwise, if `X` is `Y`, it will also filter on `a.Name`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!